# Two htaccess files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a question about using multiple `.htaccess` files - I couldn't find the answer to this after looking elsewhere on stackoverflow, so I hope you guys can help.

I currently have one `.htaccess` file in the root of my site, which performs a simple url rewrite:

```
Options -MultiViews
# CheckSpelling off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

I'm currently working on the second phase of development of this site, and I've made a replica in a subfolder (e.g. www.abcdef.com/new/). The trouble is, at the moment if I click a link on this replica site, it redirects me to the root, original page, whereas I want it to go to the equivalent page in the new/ folder. I've put another `.htaccess` file in this new/ folder, which however doesn't have any noticeable effect:

```
Options -MultiViews
# CheckSpelling off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /new/index.php?url=$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

So my question is: is it permissible to have another `.htaccess` file in a subfolder like this? And if so, why aren't the above lines working?

Thanks in advance for any ideas on this!

Comment: You can have as many .htaccess levels as you want, but they're processed in order of directory tree depth. If a higher .htaccess redirects elsewhere before a lower .htaccess gets reached, the lower one will never even get loaded/parsed/executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say

> The trouble is, at the moment if I click a link on this replica site,
>   it redirects me to the root, original page, whereas I want it to go to
>   the equivalent page in the new/ folder.

Could it be that you are using absolute links in your pages and not relative ones? For instance if a link looks like `"/sample"`, when in your main site it will link to `http://.../sample` and the same is true if the link is inside a page under `"/new/"`. If you'd use just `"sample"` then that would resolve as `http://..../sample` or `http://...../new/sample`, depending on the URL of the page.

Comment: Thanks, you're right - I'm using absolute links, i.e. /sample. Thing is, there are hundreds of these links in the original site, so I can't change them. Do you know if there's a way of rewriting them to go to the subfolder?

Comment: I don't think there is an quick solution to this. Normally they should not begin with a "/". Can you do a search in files for `"/`? Perhaps this search will find all your "mis-rooted" hrefs?

Comment: Ok, getting somewhere. Most of the links are in a db, so I've modified the code that writes them to the page to remove the initial "/". However these are still rewriting to the root! I thought that might have been the answer to my problems...

Comment: Scratch that -- browser must have been caching the old code. It's now working! Thanks a lot for your help CyberDude!

Comment: Glad to have been of help. BTW, I guess you can also ditch your second `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to have multiple .htaccess files, and the system is designed to work the way you want it to.

You're setting `RewriteBase`, which [explicitly sets the base URL-path (not filesystem directory path!) for per-directory rewrites](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

So it seems like your requests would be rewritten to `/new/new/index.php`, a path and directory which probably doesn't exist on your filesystem (thus not meeting your `RewriteCond`s) and such is being redirected to your /index.php 404.

As a test, perhaps try changing the `ErrorDocument` to:

`ErrorDocument` 404 /new/index.php

If you see rewritten calls go to this then it might indeed be your `RewriteBase`.

Comment: They're not going to the 404 -- they go to the correct page but in the original site, not the copy in new/. This is probably because, as CyberDude says below, I'm using absolute links. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Having a second htaccess file in a subdirectory shouldn't be an issue, and as far as I can tell, your two look okay.

Are you sure the links in the site are correct? (ex, they are `/new/foo`, not just `/foo`)?

Comment: No, the links are just to /foo, not to /new/foo. I was hoping that I'd be able to preserve the existing links (of which there are hundreds) and redirect them to the local folder (new/).

Comment: That would involve rewriting the HTML content, which `mod_rewrite` doesn't do. You could do some terrible, awful magic involving checking the referrer field… But that would truly be a last resort, as it would break when ever someone copy+pastes a link.

Comment: David, thanks for your help, you and cyberdude were right, and now I've tweaked the absolute links it's working. Cheers.